# Удаление строк в TStringList

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, delphi-xe, delphi-xe7, delphi-xe5

При удалении всех строк где есть слово "Del" сообщение об ошибке: **List index out of bounds (2)**

```
var
  L, K: TStringList;
  i: integer;
begin
  L := TStringList.Create;
  L.LoadFromFile(ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName) + 'f.txt');
  for i := 0 to L.Count - 1 do
  begin
    if pos('Del', L.Strings[i]) > 0 then
      L.delete(i);
    L.SaveToFile(ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName) + 'f.txt');
  end;
  L.Free;
end;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы "рубите сук, на котором сидите" или "выдергиваете коврик у себя из-под ног".

```
for i := L.Count - 1 downto 0 do
```

И вынесите `L.SaveToFile` из цикла.

Comment: Благодарен. Работает. Убрал и с цикла тоже.